# Should we be using redux in the following case?

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I'm working on an enterprise application which is huge on forms, there are pages and pages full of forms. Normally when it's just form, we could simply use a library like formik or react-hook-forms, but what I see time and again is when something changes, there's a business requirement to do something, which means I'm mutating form values programmatically.

We are currently using `useEffect` and put all those business logic side effects on components, but then it feels like I'm mixing view with business logic.

My instinct however is to use `redux`, and use `redux-saga` to manage all the side effects and complexity this way my UI is pure and is easy to write tests for. And redux-saga handles the business logic and side effect which is where they should belong anyway IMO, I want to know what the community is doing in this case.

My case, forms aren't as simple as displaying forms, and on submit, handle data, we also need to handle when something changes, we have some business logic and sometimes we actually update other values.

For things like this input is disabled when this checkbox is disabled it doesn't need redux, what about the rest? What are you guys doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made a decision based on different aspects, because redux is too verbose, we didn't want to use it, but that's not how engineers choose tech.

We decided to give weights to each points:

- Performance (5)
- Duplication of states (5)
- Ease of handling side effects (separation of concerns) (10)
- Learning Curve (3)
- Unit testing easeness (7)
- Debugging (Dev Experience) (5)
- Verbosity (less verbose is better) (5)

When we evaluated these, redux with saga came out top, sure formik has it's strength, but our whole App is just forms, and those forms aren't as simple as rendering and doing some minor side effects, it's huge form and side effects happen in such a complex ways, that just being able to track down issues using devtools is already huge.

Another thing is having a redux-saga layer helped, anyway, that's how we made the decision, but 99.9% of forms should continue using formik, but unfortunately we're at that 0.1% where redux scales with number of developers (5000+ dev in company, 50+ actively contributing to this project), and redux having devtools and ability to separate side effects, exploring data etc just made more sense.

Please choose your own when you need it.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1287#issuecomment-175351978 Dan says use redux if it matters globally OR is **mutated in complex ways** our form is mutated in such a complex ways that it's very difficult to maintain code in future, formik made it easy to write code, but redux makes it easy to debug and maintain. (for us)

Answer (score 1):

We've integrated Redux in our project just because everyone is always talking about `Redux` in terms on `ReactJS` and we've figured out that it's a bit overhead and now complicates our code a LOT (we're using `redux-observable` for side effects).

Just ask yourself a single questions -

> Are we going to share state between forms/pages/sections of the app?

If every form is separate and doesn't have anything to do with other parts of your application, so you don't need any kind of global state, `Redux` is overhead. You might want to consider structuring your app a bit better, move side-effects in your own hooks and just fully decouple your presentation from business logic - code being in `useEffect`, which happens to be in your component doesn't necessarily mean that it's part of UI logic, because you could easily move it in some kind of wrapper/service or later on to some kind of side-effect library (like `redux-saga`, `redux-observable` or something else).

Overall advice - don't overthink it and make it complicated, just try separating application concerns in simplest possible way and then along the road you'll start noticing what needs refactoring, code duplication which can be reused and whether or not you should introduce some kind of library that you can benefit from.

Comment: I agree.  If some state must be shared it with (non-child) components, I put it in redux.  Otherwise, I put it in local state and move it to a global store *only when it becomes necessary*

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a very similar project with forms constantly resulting in side effects (fetch backend for input validation or autocomplete lists, dynamically change fields according to other field values etc.).

I used formik with the `useField()` hook, which allows you to read/write any field value/error anywhere inside the `<Formik>` tree.

Given this convenience, I wrapped the view components with logic components where the side effects are done in the logic component and just returns a view component to render. Both hooked into the fields with `useField()` but you might really take it to a more functional approach by passing the values/callbacks from the logic component to the view via props. This way you can easily swap out the view values with a different logic (creating a new form and editing an existing form both share the same view but use different logics).

Answer (score -1):

I see no reason to use either `redux` and `redux-sagas` here.
You could simply use `context` API instead of redux. As far as `redux-sagas` is concerned. You could simply separate your `API` into different functions and keep it separately from your views.

redux-sagas are not worth it in my opinion. It is bloated and requires a learning curve about the API for the next developer. You want to keep the enterprise applications as simple as possible to keep in mind that, the next developer doesn't need to learn a bunch of APIs to edit your form. It's just a bunch of forms. Keep it simple.

Use `formik` and store all your state values in the localStorage on every `handlePress` so that it persists on refresh and on pressing the back button. Written a lot of complicated forms even with payments. `Formik` is literally everything you need.

And that would definitely be it. I would argue you could get away with using just `formik` instead of context API.

TLDR :-

It's just a bunch of forms.
It's just a bunch of API calls.
No need to overcomplicate things.

Use the native API like `context` or a form library.
Separate your API into an API folder.
And more importantly, store all your form values

- in a cookie, if you want it to expire,
- or in sessionStorage if you don't want to share data across tabs.
- or just localStorage

Comment: The problem is "it's just bunch of simple forms" don't hold true in my case, there are so many areas where form mutation is required sometimes after showing a modal, and sometimes even doing an API calls, It's currently working with formik, but my only issue is that it's getting too complicated to debug, maintain and write tests for.

Comment: Write e2e tests, it may take time. Writing unit tests is literally worthless. Since requirements change all the time, there's no point in writing test unless it goes into staging. Last but not the least,  "it's just a bunch of simple forms" holds true for most cases. It's about how we perceive the requirement. If you separate your base library well from the application, it becomes simple. If you're mingling everything in your component, it gets hard to debug. All you're looking for is patterns we could make things easy, the pattern only emerges after couple of iteration of the project.

Comment: I do not agree with not having unit tests, for all the edge cases, there should be unit tests, for happy paths, e2e should be written as well.

Comment: It is very hard to do unit testing in UIs. In development, since you're making changes live every time you change the code, in most cases you will find bugs then and there. All we ever needed was someone in our team to do manual testing well because, in forms, you cannot possibly test everything. Plus developers have an inherent bias against their own code, which allows them to be blind for edge cases. In my experience,  UI tests were literally fruitless. Most bugs were fixed manually when it went to staging. Since most were just pure function returning UIs. There was no point testing them.